# Asignar valores a un vector 2d en c++

Tags: c++, array, poo, 2d

Estoy intentando asignarle valores a un vector 2d en c++
Así es como esta definido, donde filas y columnas son enteros definidos.

```
vector < vector <int>> vec(filas , vector <int> (columnas));
```

lo que le quiero asignar a cada espacio del vector son caracteres que están en un archivo pbm que claramente contiene solo unos y ceros

```
char i;
FILE* file;
file = fopen("archivo.pbm", "r");
```

luego de esta manera le estoy pasando valores a cada uno de sus "casillas",

```
for (int h=0; h<filas; h++){
    for (int j=0; j<columnas; j++){ 
        while((i=fgetc(file))!=EOF){
            vec[h][j] = i;
        }
    } 
}
```

pero luego al imprimir por pantalla los valores del vector, resulta que solo contiene ceros y curiosamente en vec[0][0], almacena un '10'

```
for (int h=0; h<filas; h++){
        for (int j=0; j<columnas; j++) 
            cout << vec[h][j];
    cout <<endl; 
}

fclose(file);
```

si alguien pudiera indicarme por que al asignar los valores de esta forma, no resulta, de antemano muchas gracias!

```
vec[h][j] = i;
```

Comment: Posiblemente te falta asignar tamaño a tus vectores, pero es una conjetura ¿podrías poner tu `main`?

Comment: Hola paula, todo lo que adjunte anteriormente, corresponde a codigo que esta en el constructor por defecto o "sin parametros" de mi clase, en la funcion main de mi codigo lo unico que hago es instanciar mi clase.                                                                                                      int main(){
    Class *obj = new Class();
    return 0;
}

Comment: poque no utilizas vec[h].push_back(i) en vez de vec[h][j] = i; y que tamano le das al vector, cuanto es filas, esta filas con un valor al llegar a la declaracion del vector?

Comment: filas y columnas son valores enteros, que coinciden exactamente con las dimensiones del archivo del cual estoy extrayendo los chars, al usar vec[h].push_back(i), ¿no estaría solamente dando valores a la primera fila?

Comment: Hola @jarscs el `int main(){ Class *obj = new Class(); return 0; }` no responde mi pregunta; por desgracia ese código no muestra dónde se asigna el tamaño a tus vectores, ni como se inicializan ¿puedes poner el cuerpo de `Class()` por favor?

Comment: Paula! muchas gracias por tu interès y ganas de ayudar, pero ya encontre la solucion al problema, la cosa es que el while((i=fgetc(file))!=EOF), al estar dentro de los 2 for, solo estaba guardando el archivo completo en el indice [0][0] del vector, toda esa parte de los 2 for y el while, lo reemplaze por esto: int x = 0; int y = 0; while((i=fgetc(file))!=EOF && (x < filas) && (y < columnas)){ if(y < columnas - 1){ v_in[x][y] = i; y++; } else if(y = columnas -1){ v_in[x][y] = i; y = 0; x++;} } y ahora funciona sin problemas, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

-Todas las veces que igualas *i* a *vec* estás sobreescribiendo su valor, por culpa del while el valor final otorgado y el que se va a imprimir por pantalla es el último del archivo de texto (por esa razón tienes todos los valores repetidos).
Deberias cambiar la función getc() por fscanf() la cual lee hasta encontrarse con el siguiente caracter 'extraño' y eliminar el while.

El código se quedaría así:

```
for (int h=0; h<filas; h++){
    for (int j=0; j<columnas; j++){ 
         int number;
         fscanf(file,%d,&number);
         vec[h][j] = number;
    } 
}
```